# retrofit with rxjava handling network exceptions globally

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I am trying to handle exceptions in app on global level, so that retrofit throws an error i catch it in some specific class with logic for handling those errors.

I have an interface

```
@POST("/token")
AuthToken refreshToken(@Field("grant_type") String grantType, @Field("refresh_token") String refreshToken);
```

and observables

```
/**
 * Refreshes auth token
 *
 * @param refreshToken
 * @return
 */
public Observable<AuthToken> refreshToken(String refreshToken) {
    return Observable.create((Subscriber<? super AuthToken> subscriber) -> {
        try {
            subscriber.onNext(apiManager.refreshToken(REFRESH_TOKEN, refreshToken));
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

When i get 401 from server (invalid token or some other network related error) i want to refresh the token and repeat the rest call. Is there a way to do this with rxjava for all rest calls with some kind of observable that will catch this error globally, handle it and repeat the call that throw-ed it?

For now i am using subject to catch the error on .subscribe() like this

```
private static BehaviorSubject errorEvent = BehaviorSubject.create();

public static BehaviorSubject<RetrofitError> getErrorEvent() {
    return errorEvent;
}
```

and in some call

```
getCurrentUser = userApi.getCurrentUser().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    (user) -> {
                        this.user = user;
                    },
                    errorEvent::onNext
            );
```

then in my main activity i subscribe to that behaviour subject and parse the error

```
SomeApi.getErrorEvent().subscribe(
            (e) -> {
                //parse the error
            }
    );
```

but i cant repeat the call for the observable that throw the error.

Comment: Can you show how you chain right now the `refreshToken()` observable with the other calls?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to use the operator [`onErrorResumeNext(Func1 resumeFunction)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#onErrorResumeNext(rx.functions.Func1)), better explained in the [official wiki](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators#onerrorresumenext):

> The **onErrorResumeNext( )** method returns an Observable that mirrors the behavior of the source Observable, unless that Observable invokes onError( ) in which case, rather than propagating that error to the Subscriber, onErrorResumeNext( ) will instead begin mirroring a second, backup Observable

In your case I would put something like this:

```
getCurrentUser = userApi.getCurrentUser()
.onErrorResumeNext(refreshTokenAndRetry(userApi.getCurrentUser()))
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(...)
```

where:

```
    private <T> Func1<Throwable,? extends Observable<? extends T>> refreshTokenAndRetry(final Observable<T> toBeResumed) {
        return new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends T>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<? extends T> call(Throwable throwable) {
                // Here check if the error thrown really is a 401
                if (isHttp401Error(throwable)) {
                    return refreshToken().flatMap(new Func1<AuthToken, Observable<? extends T>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Observable<? extends T> call(AuthToken token) {
                            return toBeResumed;
                        }
                    });
                }
                // re-throw this error because it's not recoverable from here
                return Observable.error(throwable);
            }
        };
    }
```

Note also that this function can be easily used in other cases, because it's not typed with the actual values emitted by the resumed Observable.

Comment: Added to the above answer, I'd to make use of `defer()` operator to avoid retrying the request with old observable. Code: `onErrorResumeNext(refreshTokenAndRetry(Observable.defer(() -> userApi.getCurrentUser())))`. Hope useful to someone :)

Comment: @blizzard thank you for your comment. It turned out that in my case your suggestion is very important

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public Observable<List<MessageEntity>> messages(String accountId, int messageType) {
    return mMessageService.getLikeMessages(messageType)
            .onErrorResumeNext(mTokenTrick.
                    refreshTokenAndRetry(mMessageService.getLikeMessages(messageType)));
}
```