# show dialog on network error using Retrofit and Rxjava

Tags: android, error-handling, retrofit, rx-android

We are building an app using Retrofit to communicate with server, and if there is a network error,  a dialog (equivalently, a toast) should be showed and the request will be redone after user clicking the dialog. 
The problem there is that we want to handle it **globally**, instead of writing duplicated code around every request. using `onErrorResumeNext()` as described by a.bertucci in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201420/retrofit-with-rxjava-handling-network-exceptions-globally) with **observable view event** looks perfect but unfortunately it runs in `Retrofit.Idle` thread and can't start any UI element. Is it possible to solve that?

A failed example:

```
public static <T> Func1<Throwable, ? extends Observable<? extends T>> retryOnNetworkError(final Activity activity, final Observable<T> toBeResumed) {
    return new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends T>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<? extends T> call(Throwable throwable) {
            if (throwable instanceof RetrofitError &&
                    RetrofitUtils.isNetworkError((RetrofitError) throwable)) {

                return dialog(activity, R.string.dialog_title_network_error, R.string.dialog_msg_network_error)
                        .filter(ok -> ok)
                        .flatMap(ok -> toBeResumed);
            }
            return Observable.error(throwable);
        }
    };
}

public static Observable<Boolean> dialog(Context context, int title, int message) {
    return Observable.create((Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) -> {
        final AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, which) -> {
                    subscriber.onNext(true);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, (dialog, which) -> {
                    subscriber.onNext(false);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                })
                .create();
        // cleaning up
        subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(ad::dismiss));
        ad.show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you share where you call the `retryOnNetworkError` method? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @Luccas, I couldn't find the code because I had given up on this way months ago, instead, I use a common error handler at every request like  // Observable.subscribe(data->{}, error-> CommonHandler.handle(context, error));

Answer (score 0):

You can't show UI element in an Observable. You need to run it on UI thread.I had the same error and this was my solution :

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            AlertDialog(Activity, "Information : ", R.drawable.box_info, "Empty !").show;
                        }
                    });  

 public Observable<Boolean> add(Objet myObj) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribeFunc<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Subscription onSubscribe(Observer<? super Boolean> observer) {
            System.out.println("In Observable ! ");
            try {
                observer.onNext(MyObjet.callmethod()); //callMethod retunr a boolean
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            MyAlertDialog(mActivity, "My Title : ", R.drawable.box_info, "My Text");
                        }
                    });
                observer.onCompleted();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                observer.onError(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Subscriptions.empty();
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.threadPoolForIO());
}
```

With this method you can able to call a Dialog in Thread.