# Rx-Java centralized error handling

Tags: android, retrofit, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I use Retrofit as network library with Rx-Java. I want to make some centralized error checking for most requests and handle errors or pass it to subscriber's `onError()` if I cannot handle it. How could I do this?

Something like this

```
 projectListObservable
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .timeout(App.NETWORK_TIMEOUT_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .retry(App.NETWORK_RETRY_COUNT)
    .onError(e -> {
     if (e instanseOf HttpError && ((HttpError)e).getCode == 403){
        App.getInstance.getNetworkManager.reAuth();
     } else {
        throw(e);
     }})
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(new ProjectListSubscriber());
```

Also, I should stop retrying in that case, but keep retry if it's a network problem (`instanceof IOException`).

Comment: found good answer in different question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201420/retrofit-with-rxjava-handling-network-exceptions-globally

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to implement too many tihngs with a single observable.

You can have some HttpErrorHandler which will have method

```
boolean fix(Exception e)
```

if error handler fixed the exception(renew token etc) return true. You can have differrent error handlers for different cases or one for everything. TokenErrorHandler RetryErrorHandler and then make a chain.

If all error hadlers return false, throw this exception to the up level

Comment: How will I integrate this HttpErrorHandler with Rx?
Will rx understand that if fix returns true - it should retry observable (send one more request) and if false - call next handler's fix method or subscriber's onError?

Comment: I think you can use onErrorResumeNext() which returns new observable, with for loop and handler.fix() calls

Comment: @user1306579 Looks like a solution that can help me out with my problem. Could you maybe post an answer showing a way to chain error handlers for retrofit calls before they reach the onNext onError methods?