# Is doOnCompleted a valid way to handle token authentication?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, observable, subscriber

I was wondering about token authentication with Retrofit/RxJava.
I was refactoring my code to use a DataManager, such that the activity evokes a method in the presenter, the presenter subscribes to the datamanager.getTrips which is then responsible for the call to the api.

I want to make sure that my accesstoken is valid, and if it is not generate it first and then complete the task. Would doOnCompleted be a good way of achieving this or is there a better way?

```
/*In DataManager, service is the REST Interface*/
public Observable<VtTripResponseModel> getTrips(final String start, final String end, final String time, final String date){
        if(accessToken.isValid()){
            return service.getTrip(accessToken.getAccessString(),start,end,time,date,JSON_PARAM);
        }
        else{
            generateAccessToken().doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    getTrips(start, end, time, date);
                }
            });
        }

/*What do I return here? Since this will not be reached*/
    }
```

Comment: I'd just use `flatMap`.

Comment: Not specifically related to RxJava but okHttp provides an Authenticator interceptor for handling Auth failures - https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#handling-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the input, In the meantime I was flying away and found a similar, but formulated in another way post: [Retrofit with RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201420/retrofit-with-rxjava-handling-network-exceptions-globally) which had an answer in it.

My code now looks like:

```
/*In DataManager*/
 public Observable<VtTripResponseModel> getTrips(String start, String end, String time, String date){
            return service.getTrip(accessToken.getAccessString(),start,end,time,date,JSON_PARAM);
    }

public Observable<VtResponseModel> getLocationByInput(String input){
        return service.getLocationByInput(accessToken.getAccessString(),input,JSON_PARAM);
    }

/*SF 26201420*/
    public <T> Func1<Throwable,? extends Observable<? extends T>> refreshTokenAndRetry(final Observable<T> toBeResumed) {
        return new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends T>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<? extends T> call(Throwable throwable) {
                // Here check if the error thrown really is a 401
                if (isHttp401(throwable)) {
                    return service.getAccessToken(CREDENTIALS, DEVICE).flatMap(new Func1<AccessToken, Observable<? extends T>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Observable<? extends T> call(AccessToken token) {
                            accessToken = token;
                            return toBeResumed;
                        }
                    });
                }
                // re-throw this error because it's not recoverable from here
                return Observable.error(throwable);
            }
        };
    }
```

And the method in my presenter now looks like

```
public void loadRepositories(String search){
    subscription = manager.getLocationByInput(search)
              .onErrorResumeNext(manager.refreshTokenAndRetry(Observable.defer(() -> manager.getLocationByInput(search))))
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(application.defaultSubscribeScheduler())
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<VtResponseModel>() {... etc}
```

Now when the first call is made after starting the application, it will generate an accesstoken since I recieve a 401. Then that accesstoken is stored within the manager, and reused until there is a new 401 (after it has expired).

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on @david.mihola 's answear you could do it like this:

```
Observable.just(accessToken.isValid())
    .flatMap(valid -> {
        if(valid){
            return Observable.just(accessToken);
        } else {
            return generateAccessToken();
        })
    .flatMap(token -> service.getTrip(token.getAccessString(),start,end,time,date,JSON_PARAM))
```

So that the first flatMap generates token if it is not valid and if it is, then simply passes it on(this assumes that `generateToken()` returns `Observable<AccessToken>`). Second flatMap is just the thing that you wanted to do.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't quite wrap my head round how the flatmap worked after reading about it

Comment: The `if valid` path should return `Observable.just(accessToken)`

Answer (score 2):

And to give some context to @MatBos's elaboration on my comment, especially with regard to your question

> What do I return here? Since this will not be reached

It felt quite eye-opening for me when I realized that an `Observable` (or at least a cold-one, like the one we are talking about here, and the one that @MatBos described in his answer) is essentially *a description of a future computation*.

Returning an `Observable` just means that you return a blue-print for what should happen if and when someone (i. e. the code that called your `getTrips` method) actually `subscribe`s to that `Observable`. Of course, an `Observable` is *also* an asynchronous stream of events, but I think that my description here is valid, too.

So, what do you return? A description that says:

```
If someone subscribes
  1. First check if we have valid access token
  2. a) If we do, just forward the access token for later use
     b) If we don't, generate a new one access token and forward that
  3. Take whatever access token you get - it is now guaranteed to be valid and use to retrieve the trips.
  4. Forward them to the subscriber when they are ready.
```

And that description is exactly the `Observable` that @MatBos described.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, it made it alot more clear